# LL(1): non-ambiguous grammars and First/Follow Conflicts

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

I have an impression but I am not entirely sure it is right. If a grammar is not ambiguous, can it have First/Follow conflicts? I am fairly sure it can't, but I would like to have some confirmation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unambiguous grammars can have first/follow conflicts. Here's an example:

> S → Ab
>
> A → b | ε

This grammar can produce two strings, `bc` and `bbc`, and it's unambiguous. However, there's a FIRST/FOLLOW conflict on production A → b | ε, because `b` ∈ FIRST(A) and `b` ∈ FOLLOW(A) as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: :Could you tell whether FIRST/FOLLOW conflict is really an problem?Why couldn't we select the first choice perhaps based on the example you have given.Here it would be 'selecting b belongs to FIRST(A)' and ignoring the second choice i.e 'selecting b belongs to FOLLOW(A)' .Is this better rather than going on for solving FIRST/FOLLOW conflicts?

Comment: @justin You've been asking good questions in the comments. I think it might be best for you to just ask these here as their own standalone questions - you'll probably get a lot of good responses!

Comment: :Thanks for your comments.The reason is I can't post questions on stack overflow.It might be because I'm not able to frame good questions on this site.I'll try it on Computer Science where I'm able to frame questions.Is there any problem if I ask questions by contacting you through mail?

Comment: @justin I'd prefer not to chat over email. Feel free to ask at cs

Comment: :Yeah.Since I'm not good in framing questions I'm not sure whether they would accept my questions on cs.While asking questions through mail might not be a problem.